# Adding dotted line and page number to chapter in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, formatting

I am using a thesis .cls file to write my document. I want to add dotted line and page number to my chapter similar so the section below.

[image]

I've used several code such as `\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep}` but none of it works.

This is the section that I try to change in the .cls file.

```
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\normalfont\normalsize}
\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{1} 
\renewcommand\cftchapleader{\normalfont\cftdotfill{\cftchapdotsep}} 
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\MakeTextUppercase{\chaptername} }
\if@tocchapnumwords
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{:\space}
\else
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{\space\;\;}
\fi
\newlength\tmplength
```

I want it to look like this with dotted line and page number

[image]

I've tried many of the suggested solution on this page but none of it work.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is rather dependent on the class being used. So please convert your sniplet into a full example others can use and test

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea of the class or any packages that you are using. One common means of controlling the appearance of the ToC is to use the `tocloft` package. I'm guessing that somehow or other you are using `tocloft`-type code. Below is an MWE showing the aspects you might be interested in.

```
% tocchapprob.tex  SE 581405

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep} % dotted chapter leaders
\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter} % no chapter page numbers
\cftpagenumberson{chapter} % show chapter page numbers

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```

Note that the `report` class shows chapter page numbers by default but I turned them off then on again just to show how to turn on page numbers for chapters.

Comment: I'm using a thesis.cls to write my thesis. For the ToC, it is based on the `tocloft` package. My main `tex` file include many section. For the main chapters, I used `\input{mainchaps}`. 

This is  first four lines in the `.cls` file for formatting the ToC

`\RequirePackage[titles,subfigure]{tocloft}`
`\setcounter{lofdepth}{2}`
`\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}`
`\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}`

I tried editing the `.cls` file where instead of  `\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{1}` I replaced it with `\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep} % dotted chapter leaders` but the ToC remains the same.